# How to replace elements of a DataFrame from other indicated columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'v1':'a', 'v2':'b', 'v3':'1'},
                   {'v1':'2', 'v2':'c', 'v3':'d'}])
```

or

```
  v1 v2 v3
0  a  b  1
1  2  c  d
```

When the contents of a column/row is '1', '2' or '3', I would like to replace its contents with the corresponding item from the column indicated.  I.e., in the first row, column `v3` has value `"1"` so I would like to replace it with the value of the first element in column `v1`. Doing this for both rows, I should get:

```
  v1 v2 v3
0  a  b  a
1  c  c  d
```

I can do this with the following code:

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        df.loc[df['v%d' % (i+1)]==('%d' % (j+1)),'v%d' % (i+1)]= \
            df.loc[df['v%d' % (i+1)]==('%d' % (j+1)),'v%d' % (j+1)]
```

Is there a less cumbersome way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.apply(lambda row: [row['v'+v] if 'v'+v in row else v for v in row], 1)
```

This iterates over each row and replaces any value `v` with the value in column named `'v'+v` if that column exists, otherwise it does not change the value.

output:

```
  v1 v2 v3
0  a  b  a
1  c  c  d
```

Note that this will not limit the replacements to digits only. For example, if you have a column named `'va'`, it will replace all cells that contain 'a' with the value in the `'va'` column in a that row.  To limit the rows that you can replace from, you can define a list of acceptable column names. For example, lets say you only wanted to make replacements from column `v1`:

```
acceptable_columns = ['v1']

df.apply(lambda row: [row['v'+v] if 'v'+v in acceptable_columns else v for v in row], 1)
```

output:

```
  v1 v2 v3
0  a  b  a
1  2  c  d
```

**EDIT**

It was pointed out that the answer above throws an error if you have non-string types in your dataframe.  You can avoid this by explicitly converting each cell value to a string:

```
df.apply(lambda row: [row['v'+str(v)] if 'v'+str(v) in row else v for v in row], 1)
```

**ORIGINAL (INCORRECT) ANSWER BELOW**

> note that the answer below only applies when the values to replace are on a diagonal (which is the case in the example but that was not the question asked ... my bad)

You can do this with pandas' [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method and numpy's [`diag`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) method:

First select the values to replace, these will be the digits 1 to the length of your dataframe:

```
to_replace = [str(i) for i in range(1,len(df)+1)]
```

Then select values that each should be replaced with, these will be the diagonal of your data frame:

```
import numpy as np
replace_with = np.diag(df)
```

Now you can do the actual replacement:

```
df.replace(to_replace, replace_with)
```

which gives:

```
  v1 v2 v3
0  a  b  a
1  c  c  d
```

And of course if you want the whole thing as a one liner:

```
df.replace([str(i) for i in range(1,len(df)+1)], np.diag(df))
```

Add the `inplace=True` keyword arg to `replace` if you want to do the replacement in place.

Comment: This works for my sample `DataFrame` because the diagonal elements happen to be the ones to be substituted but not more generally.

Comment: It has trouble if any elements are `nan` but very nice!

Comment: Good point, its actually a problem if you have cells that are any non-string type.  I guess you can always convert the cell to a string just in case, I'll update the answer to include that case.

Answer (score 1):

I made this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'v1':'a', 'v2':'b', 'v3':'1'},
               {'v1':'2', 'v2':'c', 'v3':'d'}])

def replace_col(row, columns, col_num_dict={1: 'v1', 2: 'v2', 3: 'v3'}):
    for col in columns:
        x = getattr(row, col)
        try:
            x = int(x)
            if int(x) in col_num_dict.keys():
                setattr(row, col, getattr(row, col_num_dict[int(x)]))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return row

df = df.apply(replace_col, axis=1, args=(df.columns,))
```

It applies the function replace_col on every row. The row object's attributes which correspond to its columns get replaced with the right value from the same row. It looks a bit complicated due to the multiple set/get attribute functions, but it does exactly what is needed without too much overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 options.

## Loop over the columns and then over the mapping

```
mapping = {'1': 'v1', '3': 'v3', '2': 'v2'}

df1 = df.copy()
for column_name, column in df1.iteritems():
    for k, v in mapping.items():
        df1.loc[column == k, column_name] = df1.loc[column == k, v]
```

> df1

```
    v1  v2  v3
0   a   b   a
1   c   c   d
```

## Loop over the columns, then loop over all the 'hits'

```
df2 = df.copy()
for column_name, column in df2.iteritems():
    hits = column.isin(mapping.keys())
    for idx, item in column[hits].iteritems():
        df2.loc[idx, column_name] = df2.loc[idx, mapping[item]]
```

> df2

```
    v1  v2  v3
0   a   b   a
1   c   c   d
```

If you've chosen a way, you could reduce the 2 nested for-loops to 1 for-loop with `itertools.product`

Comment: Not sure this is less cumbersome but it is more elegant than my code!

Comment: @TedTo From what I can tell, the first variation does basically the same as your code, but with the `mapping`instead of the string formatting

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the data before convert to df

```
data = [{'v1':'a', 'v2':'b', 'v3':'1'},{'v1':'2', 'v2':'c', 'v3':'d'}]
mapping = {'1': 'v1', '3': 'v3', '2': 'v2'}
for idx,line in enumerate(data):
...     for item in line:
...         try:
...             int(line[item ])
...             data[idx][item ] = data[idx][mapping[line[item ]]]
...         except Exception:
...             pass

[{'v1': 'a', 'v2': 'b', 'v3': 'a'}, {'v1': 'c', 'v2': 'c', 'v3': 'd'}]
```